# Android - Refit throws UnknownHostException unexpectedly

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, httpclient, refit

I'm trying to implement [Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit) using Xamarin and for some reason it throws a UnknownHostException (UHExc) if I was previously not connected to wifi while the app was open. This doesn't happen consistently though.

I have these two calls to Refit's instantiation of my "Refit-interface": **PostLoginAsync** and **GetDataAsync**, as shown below (the guide I've been following is [here](http://arteksoftware.com/resilient-network-services-with-xamarin/)):

```
public async Task<SomeClass> PostLogin(string user, string password)
{
    SomeClass response = null;

    var loginTask = apiService.UserInitiated.PostLoginAsync(new RequestBody(user: user, password: password));
    response = await FireWebTask(loginTask);

    return response;
}
```

and

```
private async Task<List<Data>> GetRemoteDataAsync(string args)
{
    List<Data> list = null;

    var getDataTask = apiService.UserInitiated.GetDataAsync(args);
    list = await FireWebTask(getDataTask);

    return list;
}
```

The "Refit-interface" looks somewhat like this:

```
...
[Post("/relative/url/to/login")]
Task<SomeClass> PostLoginAsync([Body(BodySerializationMethod.Json)] RequestBody requestBody);

[Get("/relative/url/to/data")]
Task<List<Data>> GetDataAsync([Header("SomeHeader")] string args);
...
```

When I open the app with no connection to the internet and try to send the **PostLogin**-request, I get an UHExc as expected. If I then turn on the wifi and try again (without closing the app) I get the UHExc again, only this time with almost no delay as the first time (as if the exception was cached??). Restarting the app and trying again without disconnecting the wifi works fine.

If I do the exact same thing with the second request (**GetData**) I first get an UHExc (obviously) but when reconnecting the wifi it works flawlessly. So it seems to me like the POST-request caches the exception or something and throws it repeatedly without trying to connect at all. How can I solve this (whatever the problem actually is)?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this as I am having a similar issue where Refit appears to cache exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and after some testing discovered that the issue is with the [Fusillade](https://github.com/paulcbetts/Fusillade) library. Now the initial problem is that the [fixing changes](https://github.com/jgfaulk/Fusillade/commit/433c985f11444c85abde9df28450fc82b7210f85) are not reflected in the NuGet packages so you need to download the latest source from the [Github repo](https://github.com/paulcbetts/Fusillade) and reference the newer dlls.

Looks like the underlying issue is due to the failed requests getting [enqueued and played back](https://github.com/paulcbetts/Fusillade/issues/14) even though the request resulted in a WebException.

I included the latest code into my project and confirmed that they are working.